# group timestamps by 20 second intervals

Tags: python, datetime, python-itertools

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
d = datetime.now()
data = [d + timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(100)]

# prepare and group the data
from itertools import groupby

def get_key(d):
    # group by 30 minutes
    k = d + timedelta(minutes=-(d.minute % 20))
    return datetime(k.year, k.month, k.day, k.hour, k.minute, 0)

g = groupby(sorted(data), key=get_key)

# print data
for key, items in g:
    print(key)
    for item in items:
        print('-', item)
```

I have a large dataset of timestamps, and I want to group it into 20 second windows. The above code works really well in grouping it in minutes, but I cannot get it to work for grouping in 20 seconds

Comment: The `timedelta` constructor has a keyword `seconds` and `datetime` has a field `second` so why wouldn't your same approach work?

Comment: I am not sure if I write k = d + td(seconds=-(d.second % 20)), it groups them by 1 minute intervals, I do not understand why, any thought ?

Comment: Perhaps it's because, when you created your test dataset in the third line of your program, you created all the data points one minute apart.

Comment: I tried 1 second a part but still the same thing, as if it is ignoring the seconds

Comment: In your `get_key` function, the last field in the last line should be seconds.  You set it to 0 always.  It should be `k.second`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it worked

Answer (score 4):

The group needs to have a seconds field:

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt

def get_key(d):
    # group by 20 seconds
    k = d - dt.timedelta(seconds=d.second % 20)
    return dt.datetime(k.year, k.month, k.day, k.hour, k.minute, k.second)
```

**Test Code:**

```
d = dt.datetime.now()
data = [d + dt.timedelta(seconds=i*5) for i in range(20)]

# prepare and group the data
import itertools as it

g = it.groupby(sorted(data), key=get_key)

# print data
for key, items in g:
    print(key)
    for item in items:
        print('-', item)
```

**Results:**

```
2017-04-07 17:51:00
- 2017-04-07 17:51:16.372000
2017-04-07 17:51:20
- 2017-04-07 17:51:21.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:26.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:31.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:36.372000
2017-04-07 17:51:40
- 2017-04-07 17:51:41.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:46.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:51.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:51:56.372000
2017-04-07 17:52:00
- 2017-04-07 17:52:01.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:06.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:11.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:16.372000
2017-04-07 17:52:20
- 2017-04-07 17:52:21.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:26.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:31.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:36.372000
2017-04-07 17:52:40
- 2017-04-07 17:52:41.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:46.372000
- 2017-04-07 17:52:51.372000
```